# GearVR Samsung browser - vrdisplaypresentchange not firing on exit

Tags: gear-vr, webvr

GearVR Samsung browser - vrdisplaypresentchange not firing on exit

I can catch when it starts presenting with the 'vrdisplaypresentchange' event and also with VRDisplay.isPresenting (returns true when presenting), but the problem is that 'vrdisplaypresentchange' doesn't fire when the user stops presenting ( when they click the back button ) and VRDisplay.isPresenting still returns true after exiting..

Obviously this is a bug with GearVR's webvr implementation, but I'm still searching for type of some work-around..

Note:

- There doesn't seem to be any way to capture the backbutton event, it
  doesn't trigger a mousedown or keydown event
- Standard fullscreen events are not fireing on exit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's no workaround for this. But it has been fixed in latest update (4.2, on 8/22) so won't need to.